# Heroku and Django: No default language could be detected for this app

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-3.6

I have followed the instructions given under a tutorial ([Link here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/68sc3ihna7qdaiu/test.py?dl=0)). I have even included the runtime.txt file with the proper version of Python. I have searched everywhere but no solution seems to work. My GitHub project link for reference:

https://github.com/MithilRocks/chakri

The error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Mithil Bhoras\Documents\GitHub\chakri\chakri> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 90, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (80/80), done.
Writing objects: 100% (90/90), 8.78 MiB | 234.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 90 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
remote:                         See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to chakrilevels.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/chakrilevels.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/chakrilevels.git'
```

Comment: in https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name is an option to "Add a Buildpack" choose Python and thats it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, the same solution as @hansTheFranz's comment, but from the command line:

- At app creation: `heroku create --buildpack heroku/python app_name`
- For an existing app: `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`

Also, the official [Heroku Buildpack: Python](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) documentation could help.

Answer (score 0):

you can write requirements.txt by small litter to "r" not Requirements.txt
if you do not have requirements.txt file
you should make this file
in "cmd" can write this line

```
freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I don't know that this answers the question.